# Why doesn't parashat Pinchas start at the beginning of the story of Pinchas (a few pesukim earlier)?

Tags: parsha-torah-portion, pinchas, zealotry

The story of Pinchas begins at the end of parashat Balak ([Bamidbar chapter 25:1-9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.25.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)).

Why does the Torah begin parashat Pinchas in verse 10? It seems logical to have started the parasha of Pinchas with... the story of Pinchas only a few pesukim earlier, rather than start it after the story which he is known for.

Comment: The question is even stronger since the break happens at quite a negative conclusion

Comment: The break happens with the end of the mageifa.

Comment: If we'd add these 9 verses forward to Pinchas, the parsha would become the longest at 177 verses (and Balak would become 95). Maybe that's why

Comment: [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Numbers.25.1.2) cites a midrash that says the women coming to the Jews was Bilaam's suggestion.